# yii changing removing and renameing column names

Tags: php, excel, csv, yii, export

I currently have a return that sends back a list of items in an auction.  What I am trying to do is clean up the array before I export it to a excel spread sheet. I can use yii or php to clean up the select before exporting, I just need to know how to do it.  I know how to do it with a mysql statement but that is frowned upon in the yii world.

This is my current code:

```
$auction = Btmauctions::model()->findByPk($id);
$listings = $auction->btmListings;
$filename = 'last_lot_export.csv';
$csv = new ECSVExport($listings);
$csv->toCSV($filename); // returns string by default
Yii::app()->getRequest()->sendFile( $auction->name.'_lots.csv' , file_get_contents( $filename ) );
```

This exports a csv that looks like this:

```
ID| auction_ID| lot| description | manufacturer | model|more_info|  condition
21  10  12  FANUC CIRCUIT BOARD Fanuc   A20B-9000-0180/09C      3
20  10  1   FANUC CIRCUIT BOARD Fanuc   A20B-0008-0242/023A     4
22  10  18  FANUC CIRCUT BOARD  Fanuc   A20B-1003-0010/12B  * A LITTLE DIRTY    3
23  10  19  FANUC CIRCUIT BOARD Fanuc   A20B-1003-0020/03A  *VERY DIRTY!!! *PLASTIC BROKEN ON RISERS!! COSMETIC ONLY!!  3
```

What I need to do is clean up the cvs automatically before exporting it so it looks like this:

```
lot|INFO              | manufacturer| model|  more info |         condition
12  FANUC CIRCUIT BOARD  Fanuc   A20B-9000-0180/09C                     3
1   FANUC CIRCUIT BOARD  Fanuc   A20B-0008-0242/023A                    4
18  FANUC CIRCUT BOARD   Fanuc   A20B-1003-0010/12B * A LITTLE DIRTY    3
19  FANUC CIRCUIT BOARD  Fanuc   A20B-1003-0020/03A *VERY DIRTY!!!
```

To summarize the changes, I need to delete the first 2 columns, and rename the 'description' column to 'INFO'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be something like this from [Human Readable headers](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/csvexport/)

```
$headers = array('header_to_change'=>'new value');
$csv->setHeaders($headers);

// or

$csv->setHeader($currentHeaderValue, $newHeaderValue);
```

and to export only the columns you want i would select only those columns. Looks like that the ECSVExport class could use CArrayDataprovider as an input. So therefore only select the columns you want to export and fill the CArrayDataprovider with it and export with your class.

But you can also use the "setCallback" function to remove the unwanted column entries or the "setExclude" function.
For both functions there is an example in the link given above.